# Registry pattern with Row Data Gateway

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am reading Martin Fowlers book i.e. Patterns of Enterprise applications: ftp://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/sourceforge/w/we/webtune/Patterns%20of%20Enterprise%20Application%20Architecture.pdf.  I have come accross the Row Data Gateway pattern and specifically the Registry pattern.  Here is a code snippet from page 149 of the book:

```
public static Person find(Long id) {
    Person result = (Person) Registry.getPerson(id);
    if (result != null) 
        return result;
    PreparedStatement findStatement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        findStatement = DB.prepare(findStatementString);
        findStatement.setLong(1, id.longValue());
        rs = findStatement.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        result = load(rs);
        return result;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new ApplicationException(e);
    } finally {
         DB.cleanUp(findStatement, rs);
    }
}
```

The code above calls the registry class, but I am not sure what the benefit of a Registry class is.  I have read the chapter on Registry classes and I am still unclear.  I understand that they are static methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the registry is acting like a cache (or an `IdentityMap` as you will soon see or might have already), where if your application already has a reference to the `Person` object, it won't go get it from the Database.

From the book

> When you want to find an object you usually start with another object
>   that has an association to it, and use the association to navigate to
>   it. Thus, if you want to find all the orders for a customer, you start
>   with the customer object and use a method on it to get the orders.
>   However, in some cases you won't have an appropriate object to start
>   with.

The `Registry` pattern is basically a holder for object references, so that you don't have to traverse complex object dependencies to get the last object in the chain. Example (you will never see in practice):

```
class Book {
    public Author author;
}

class Author {
    public City city;
}

class City {
    public String name;
}
```

You don't want to have to go through `Book -> Author` to get the `City` object.

You use `Registry` usually to keep references to global objects which is why Fowler proposes to use `static` methods, but as you can read on `page 409`, you should only rarely use this pattern `"as a last resort"`.

*Poorly contrived* Registry example

```
class CityRegistry {
    private static Map<String, City> references = new HashMap<>();
    public static void registerCity(String id, City reference) {
        references.put(id, reference);
    }

    public static City getCity(String id) {
        return references.get(id);
    }
}
```

Whenever you would create an instance of some class, you would register it in the `Registry` so that the whole application has access to it (which might cause more problems than it solves).

Comment: Why would you ever have to go through Book -> Author to get the City object? Could you provide an example of the Registry? Thanks +1.

Comment: @w0051977 You wouldn't, but in a more complicated example, you might have to in order to get to some instance way down in the object hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks.  So instead of passing id all over the place you would pass it to the registry and hold the object in the registry.

Comment: @w0051977 Yes. Martin Fowler has a few other examples/use cases starting on `page 410` of the pdf you linked.

Comment: What alternative pattern is there? as this pattern should be used as a "last resort".

Comment: @w0051977 Just as you said, keep passing the object around. It kind of depends on the situation. You could possibly rework your entire architecture so that problem doesn't come up. It's a pattern after all, you use it when you need to.

Comment: are you able to answer my other question here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/199423/mixing-fowlers-transaction-script-and-domain-model (it is another Martin Fowler question).  I thought I would ask you to answer as I found your answer to this question helpful.  Thanks.